# Replace specific values in pandas dataframe with the corresponding column name, based on a condition,

Tags: python, pandas, replace, apply

My pandas dataframe has three possible entries:

- 1 (integer)
- NaN
- arbitrary strings

An example could be created like that:

```
pd.DataFrame({'column1':['yes','some_string',np.NaN],
              'column2':[np.NaN,np.NaN,'yes']}, columns=['column1','column2'])
```

I want to achieve the following:

1. Wherever the element value is `yes` I want it to be replaced with the column name `column1` or `column2`;
2. When the element is NaN, it should be untouched
3. If there is a string `some_string` I want to put it into brackets, attach `and` and the corresponding column name: `'column1 and (some_string)'`

I have tried a conditional **df.apply** but it did not work because it is applied on Series and I don't know how to impose a condition **(=='yes')**

I also tried **pandas mask** but I don't know how to replace with different elements rather than a static one.

Comment: `df.apply` passing `axis=1` would allow you select on rows. The series labels also pass the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try adding the brackets and 'and', then [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask) out the `yes` and [`radd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html#pandas-dataframe-radd) the column names:

```
new_df = (' and (' + df + ')').mask(df.eq('yes'), '').radd(df.columns)
```

`new_df`:

```
                     column1  column2
0                    column1      NaN
1  column1 and (some_string)      NaN
2                        NaN  column2
```

---

Breakdown of steps:

```
new_df = ' and (' + df + ')'
```

```
              column1     column2
0           and (yes)         NaN
1   and (some_string)         NaN
2                 NaN   and (yes)
```

[`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html#pandas-dataframe-mask):

```
new_df = new_df.mask(df.eq('yes'), '')
```

```
              column1 column2
0                         NaN
1   and (some_string)     NaN
2                 NaN
```

[`radd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html#pandas-dataframe-radd):

```
new_df = new_df.radd(df.columns)
```

```
                     column1  column2
0                    column1      NaN
1  column1 and (some_string)      NaN
2                        NaN  column2
```

Comment: Wow, I could not solve it after hours. Although, in the last step, I am not sure how pandas knows which value from df.columns it should add to which element, but I can figure this out by myself. Thank you very much, it's perfect!